# Lista siempre guarda la ultima fila que se leyo

Tags: c#

Estoy recorriendo las filas de un archivo excel e incrementando el renglo para ir a la siguiente fila, cabe aclarar que el archivo excel se lee correctamente
le cada celda de cada fila lo que sucede es que cuando llega al `Add(info)` cada `row` debera ser agregada, y es que cuando se lee la primera todo bien al final se queda guardado
pero cuando avanza a la siguiente fila y lee los datos se guardan estos pero el anterior que se guardo se pierde y asi sucesivamente.

Cuando llega a `Save()` que es un `function` para hacer un `insert` a la BD con un `foreach` recorro la lista con todas las filas, y si me trae todas las filas
pero en todas es la ultima que se leyo, es decir; si tengo 100 filas que deberian ser diferentes las 100 filas son la ultima y tiene la misma  informacion.

```
public string RecorrerExcel()
{

    DataTable excelTable = new DataTable("ExcelFile");
    DataTable original = GetDataTableExcel();

    int renglon = 1;
    ExcelInformation info = new ExcelInformation();
    List<ExcelInformation> listaInformation = new List<ExcelInformation>();

    foreach (DataRow item in original.Rows)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < original.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            //
            switch (original.Rows[0][i].ToString())
            {

                case "XXXXX":

                    info.XXXXX = item[i].ToString();
                    break;

                case "XXXXX":

                    info.XXXXX = item[i].ToString();
                    break;

                case "XXXXX":

                    info.XXXXX = item[i].ToString();
                    break;

                case "XXXXX":

                    info.XXXXX = item[i].ToString();
                    break;

                case "XXXXX":

                    info.XXXXX = item[i].ToString();

                    renglon += 1;
                    break;

                default:
                    break;

            }                    
        }
        Add(info);   //agrega a la lista                           
    }
   Save();      //function para hacer insert    
    return ""; 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estás guardando en la lista la referencia a la misma instancia de **info**.

Para corregir esto, debes crear una instancia nueva de info dentro del ciclo...

```
public string RecorrerExcel()
{

    DataTable excelTable = new DataTable("ExcelFile");
    DataTable original = GetDataTableExcel();

    int renglon = 1;
    ExcelInformation info = new ExcelInformation();
    List<ExcelInformation> listaInformation = new List<ExcelInformation>();

    foreach (DataRow item in original.Rows)
    {
        info = new ExcelInformation(); //Acá creas una nueva instancia y no utilizas siempre la misma
        for (int i = 0; i < original.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            //
            switch (original.Rows[0][i].ToString())
            {

                case "XXXXX":

                    info.XXXXX = item[i].ToString();
                    break;

                case "XXXXX":

                    info.XXXXX = item[i].ToString();
                    break;

                case "XXXXX":

                    info.XXXXX = item[i].ToString();
                    break;

                case "XXXXX":

                    info.XXXXX = item[i].ToString();
                    break;

                case "XXXXX":

                    info.XXXXX = item[i].ToString();

                    renglon += 1;
                    break;

                default:
                    break;

            }                    
        }
        Add(info);   //agrega a la lista                           
    }
   Save();      //function para hacer insert    
    return ""; 
}
```

Del modo anterior, la lista no contendrá referencias a la misma instancia.